# Change back color of every row of a table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change the backcolor of every rows  of a table but I am not quite sure what is the best way to do it. Personally, I want to change on backcolor with ruby codes,but i dont know how :(

here is my code:

```
<% @word.each do |w| %>
                <% i=0 %>
                <% i=i+1 %>
                <% if i % 2==0 %>
 ........
```

Thank you for your helps

Babak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [cycle](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) it's exactly what you need.